# Is it possible to override single default windows keyboard-shortcuts?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I want to replace the default windows shortcut <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> with a custom (.lnk) shortcut

Is this possible - when yes: how?

Comment: I think you meant `.lnk` (stands for link) not `.ink`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) and add this simple line into its macro file:

```
#w::Run C:\Tools\mylink.lnk
```

(do not forget to run AutoHotKey **as administrator**)

Note: `#` = <kbd>Win</kbd>; `+` = <kbd>Shift</kbd>; `^` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>; `!` = <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so `^!Esc` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> etc...

AutoHotKey (free, open source) is worth exploring to find a way to other macro/hotkey/automation possibilities.

Comment: I know AutoHotKey basically, thanks for this great hint. I'll try this soon :)

Comment: @bablewa - If you are on Windows 8.1, I recommend keeping Win+W for original functionality (search through settings) and employ something unoccupied like Win+A instead.

Comment: that's like the most unneccessary function at all IMHO.

Comment: works like a charm (btw w/o admin permissions), thanks again :)

Comment: I very often experienced erratic AHK behavior if it was launched without admin permissions. Random effects were seen – hotkeys sometimes worked, sometimes not. If you sometimes experience the same, you have good reason to change this as the first thing. :)